# Generate random size-k subset from size-N (probability-weighted) set

Tags: python, random, probability, combinatorics, weighted

This problem stems from a musical training game where I must choose a random 3-note chord from the 12 available pitch-classes, but certain notes are more likely than others (so that the user can train more for weaker notes).

I thought this problem would be quite simple: consider each weight as a line segment, place all segments one after the other to make a long segment, pick a random point on this long segment, record which weight it lies on, rinse and repeat until we have k items.

The following Python code demonstrates that this technique doesn't produce the correct results:

```
# Choose k items from a set of weights
# return set of winning indices
def Choose(W,k):
    import random

    cumulative = [ sum(W[:i+1]) for i in xrange(len(W)) ]
    totalWeight = cumulative[-1]

    winners = set()
    while len(winners) < k:
        rnd = random.uniform(0.0, totalWeight)

        # Returns first element of cumulative that is >= rnd
        w = next( i for i in xrange(len(cumulative)) if cumulative[i] >= rnd )
        winners.add( w )

    return winners

def Test(N):
    x = [ list(Choose( [5,3,2], 2 )) for i in xrange(int(N/2))]
    y = sum(x, [])
    z = [y.count(i) for i in (0,1,2) ]

    print z

for i in range(10):
    Test(10000)
```

I generate 5000 random pairs from 3 weights [5,3,2]
The output logs the number of times each weight comes up
It should be 5000,3000,2000

For good measure I run the experiment 10 times:

```
python test.py 
[4173, 3331, 2496]
[4180, 3367, 2453]
[4193, 3393, 2414]
[4228, 3375, 2397]
[4207, 3388, 2405]
[4217, 3377, 2406]
[4173, 3438, 2389]
[4172, 3378, 2450]
[4174, 3371, 2455]
[4208, 3322, 2470]
```

So ~ 4200 vs 3300 vs 2400
Not  5000 vs 3000 vs 2000

Is there a simple way to understand why this doesn't work?

Is there some way of transforming the weights, maybe 'weight[i] -> ln(weight[i])' or something like this, that would give correct results?

How to achieve the correct result? (I'm more concerned about clarity of code than optimal efficiency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling without replacement with weights is a tricky problem.

First, consider your intuitive solution.  You generate 5000 pairs, and you expect 5000 of these pairs to contain a 1.  This means that every pair must contain a 1.  I suspect that this is not what you desired or expected.  To get the distribution that you expected, you could first choose 1, and then choose 2 or 3 with probability .6 or .4 respectively.

To do what I suspect you asking for, you should do something like Conditional Poisson Sampling.  I do not know of a Python module that does this, though there almost certainly is one.  The 'sampling' package in R will do it.  I know of no gentle introduction on the web.

From a practical point of view, just do what you are doing and adjust the weights so that the probabilities come close to what you want.  For what you are trying to do, precise probabilities do not seem necessary.

If you want a simple method (that is decidedly inefficient) to achieve what you want:

1) normalize the weights so that the sum of all the weights add up to the desired sample size.  With your example .5 + .3 + .2 = 2 so the normalized weights would be [1., .6, .4].

2) let p_i be the ith weight considered as a probability (they all must be less than or equal to 1 or the problem will be impossible.  Choose a sample by selecting the ith element with probability p_i

3) if the size of the drawn sample is correct output it, otherwise draw again

Here is a quick code example

```
import random
def sample(weights, sample_size):
    w = float(sum(weights))
    normweights = [x * sample_size / w for x in weights]
    samp = [random.random() < pi for pi in normweights]
    while sum(samp) != sample_size:
        samp = [random.random() < pi for pi in normweights]
    return [i for i,b in enumerate(samp) if b]

print(sample([.5,.3,.2], 2))
```

EDIT:
Ok, the above algorithm is hooey. I'll try to remember how to do it correctly.

Comment: Yes, my inner mathematician keeps sidetracking me into trying to solve abstract problems. You're right, in my particular case I don't need anything more exact than what I have. I am curious though!

Comment: If you are at a university or have access to one, you might take a look at "Sampling algorithms" by Yves Tille.  It will tell you how to compute the probabilities (it is not simple, but it will amuse your inner mathematician)

Answer (score 3):

Use [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the p parameter:

```
np.random.choice(3, size=1000, p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
```

Now try again and see what you get.

Comment: He seems to want `np.random.choice(2, size=1000, replace=False, p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])`, i.e. two separate choices from 3 items.

Comment: Thanks Emre, Numpy is full of nice surprises! Unfortunately for me I'm going to be using IronPython which doesn't support numpy.